# Angular 2 | nested arrays in reactive form with dynamically built components

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, dynamic

I'd like to build a reactive form in angular 2 and have the form component build dynamically. I've found some great tutorials on how to do this with simple forms:

https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

https://juristr.com/blog/2017/10/demystify-dynamic-angular-forms/

But I can't seem to figure out how to implement this when the data model contains an array of strings or objects. For example, consider an object of the following structure:

```
{
  'name': 'Big Name Hotel',
  'tags': [
    'clean',
    'cozy',
    'cheap'
  ],
  'locations': [
    {
      'city': 'Denver',
      'state': 'CO',
    },
    {
      'city': 'San Francisco',
      'state': 'CA',
    },
    {
      'city': 'Los Angeles',
      'state': 'CA',
    }
  ]
}
```

I can built a dynamic form component for the name element with one of the tutorials above, but how would I make it work with arrays of strings (tags) and arrays of objects (locations)?

=== EDIT FOR MORE CONTEXT ===

Here's the config data structure from one of the tutorials:

```
  config = [
    {
      type: 'input',
      label: 'Full name',
      name: 'name',
      placeholder: 'Enter your name',
    },
    {
      type: 'select',
      label: 'Favourite food',
      name: 'food',
      options: ['Pizza', 'Hot Dogs', 'Knakworstje', 'Coffee'],
      placeholder: 'Select an option',
    },
    {
      label: 'Submit',
      name: 'submit',
      type: 'button',
    },
  ];
```

What might the data structure look like for arrays of strings or arrays of objects?

Comment: What have you figured out so far, can you show us?

Comment: Not much beyond the tutorials I've posted, to be honest. I can't figure out how to configure the data structure of the form to incorporate arrays OR how the html should be structured for those arrays. But once I figure out the data structure, I think I could manage the html. I'll update the post to include a data structures example from one of the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think (can't test right now) that you can just map the array into a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

```
const form = new FormGroup({
   tags : new FormArray(tags.map(tag => new FormControl(tag)))
});
```

Comment: Yep, I can see how this would set up an array for a given form and a specific array, but I'm trying to set up the component to *dynamically* generate the form and html. 

I don't want to write custom code for a given array.

Comment: @JackVaughan So why not just use a template driven form (instead of reactive) and have the html generate the code.?

Comment: Yes, I understand I could built this with a template driven form (or even reactive), but I specifically want my component to generate dynamically - that's the key part of what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't want to write any html specific to one form.

Answer (score 0):

Using **FormBuilder**,

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }


  createForm() {
    ...

   this.form= this.fb.group({
         name: [this.data.name],
         ...
        locations: this.fb.array([])
   });

    const locationsFGs = this.data.locations.map(loc=> {
      return this.fb.group({
        city: [loc.city, Validators.required],
        state: [loc.state],
      });
    });
    const locationsFormArray: FormArray = this.fb.array(locationsFGs );
    this.form.setControl('locations', locationsFormArray);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Yerkon - but how would this dynamically build the html portion of the component?

Comment: @JackVaughan, as an example you can look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-deep-phnik3

Comment: This looks interesting - let me see if I can use this as starting point for what I'm trying to accomplish.